# Is there a way to use local transforms without pressing keys twice?

Tags: interface, transforms, customization, shortcut

If you give any object a different rotation it also has a new local orientation. You can still rotate around local axes by using <kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>X</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>/<kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>.

First press switches to global orientation.
Second press switches to local orientation.

I usually work 90% with local orientations, so its not very comfortable for my workflow.

- Can I change the order to
  first press = local
  and second press = global?
- Is there a way to jump right into local mode (<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> = local)?
- Is it even possible to access actions of double keys like <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> in the user preferences and for example switch to Trackball Rotation without pressing twice and also with a different key?

Answer (score 2):

You could set the 'Transformation orientation' to 'local' and show the translation, rotation and scaling arrow (you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd> to select multiple of them), and use these to transform your object.

[image]